# How do I create a 1 by N matrix, with elements from 1 to N (matlab)?

Tags: matlab

quick beginner MATLAB question. 
How do I create a 1 by N matrix with elements going from 1 to N?

Ex. `[1 2 3 4 ..... N]`

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do

```
[1:N];
```

The brackets are optional.

There is also another option if you want to change the increment to something other than `1`. The general pattern is

```
[ start : step : stop ];
```

So if you want only even numbers from 2 to 100, you can do

```
[2:2:100];
```

Or if you want to get numbers from 1 to 0 decrementing by .1 you can do

```
[1:-0.1:0];
```

I highly recommend you take a quick squiz through the Matlab Getting Started Guide. It covers the basics such as this.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, and you're right, I will do that.

Comment: The brackets are optional.  You can just do `x = 1:N;`.

Comment: @nibot: Yes, I mentioned that on line 3.